# SlideToggle hardware accelerated solution on android

Tags: android, jquery, css

I'm struggling to (re)create a SMOOTH jQuery slideToggle animation on mobile device, specifically Chrome on Android.

What I tried so far:

1. jQuery slideToggle. Works, but the animation is incredibly sloppy.
2. CSS3 Transition. A tiny improvement over jQuery solution, but still sloppy.
3. Translate3D. According to the articles I've read, it should force hardware acceleration on mobile browsers, but well, it doesn't, so again, the animation is ugly (I am using Galaxy S4 with latest version of Chrome).

I've been unable to come across a solution that would actually work, hence, I came here for help. Is there any unified solution to make jQuery / CSS3 animations smooth on mobile devices? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: When you say "mobile device", have you considered that there are old Android devices that have <512MB of RAM and 500GHz processors?

Comment: Put up some code or style sheets so we can better assist